# Did I share state correctly outside angular directive? (parent scope / $rootScope issue)

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

I have two elements on my page which are not nested in some way. With attributes on the first one, I would like to set the content of the second one, like so:

```html
<body>
    <input info="This is some info"></input>
    <div>{{info}}</div>
</body>
```

I know something similar can be done as described in "[AngularJS - Attribute directive input value change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16308322/angularjs-attribute-directive-input-value-change)", but in my situation the content of the attribute *is* the modelvalue. Moreover, I'm already using the `ng-model` to handle the input's value.

Finally I solved the problem like so:

```html
<body>
    <input infobox info="This is some info"></input>
    <div>{{info}}</div>
</body>
```

```js
app.directive('infobox', function() {
    return {
        restrict : 'A',
        scope : {
            info : '@info'
        },
        controller: function($rootScope, $scope) {
            $rootScope.info = $scope.info;
        }
    };
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/P8wgy/1/)

So I'm transferring the value bypassing any isolated scope by going directly to the `$rootScope`, but it feels like a cop out. Essentially I don't know what controller or scope might be up the chain, since I need to be able to use this component anywhere.

One other solution is to have a parent controller for the entire page, but that would simply be a pseudo root scope again. Yet another more cumbersome solution would be to have two directives or controllers and communicate using events almost like a bus. It would work, but let's not do that.

Is there a 'clean' way to do this?

**/edit**

Here's a clean solution that *should* work (and in jsfiddle it does):

```html
<body>
     <div info="this is some info"></div>
     <div>{{info}}</div>
</body>
```

```js
app.directive('info', function() {
    return {
        restrict : 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModel) {
            scope.info = attrs.info;
        }
    };
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8M6m7/1/).

In my real life scenario however the value is stuck somewhere in the chain. Is it possible a parent directive with isolated scope is blocking the cascade all the way up?

**/edit2**

Here's a solution I thought surely would have worked. It involves three directives of which one is the parents to both others. A combination of suggested solutions in the comments:

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8M6m7/3/)

In my own code, however, it still doesn't work. As simple as it might seem, `infoManager.info` remains `undefined`.

Comment: Assignments to child scopes don't cascade up at all.

Comment: Yeah, I guess what I meant is: as soon as an isolated scope is created, you effectively make the values added to the scope invisible to the 'outside' world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, I got it finally. The last edit had it close, but I was reading info from the controller, not the scope the controller was for.

Solution is as follows:

```html
<body>
    <div infomanager>
        <div info="'this is some info'"></div>
        <div showinfo></div>
    </div>
</body>
```

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.directive('infomanager', function() {
    return {
        controller: function($scope) {
            this.scope = $scope;
        }
    };
});

app.directive('info', function() {
    return {
        restrict : 'A',
        require: '^infomanager',
        scope : {
            info : '=info'
        },
        link: function(scope, element, attrs, infoManager) {
            infoManager.scope.info = scope.info;
        }
    };
})

app.directive('showinfo', function(){
    return {
        template:'{{info}}',
        require:'^infomanager'
    }
})
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TUN67/)

Here's a better example to demonstrate this with: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/t9NRG/1/)

Answer (score 2):

There is another approach I used recently with a similiar situation (also I do revert to "rootscope jail break" and "event emit/listen" patterns to solve other problems) that might work for you: lets say we have this directive:

```
app.directive('infobox', function() {
    return {
        restrict : 'A',
        scope : {
            info : '@info'
        },
        controller: function($rootScope, $scope) {
            //$rootScope.info = $scope.info;
            this.setInfo = function(data){
              $scope.info = data;
            }
            this.getInfo = function(){
                return $scope.info;
            }

        }
    };
})
```

now I can add another directive for showing `{{info}}`:

with the html:

```
app.directive('showinfo', function(){
   return {
    restrict:'A',
    template:'<div>{{info}}</div>',
    require:'^infobox', //this is where the magic happens
    link:function(scope,element,attrs,parentCtrl){ //notice that now er have a "parentctrl, with everything that is on 'this' in the required direcive
//you can set a watch for this etc..
  scope.info = parentCtrl.getInfo();
  }

 }

})
```

hope this helps!

Comment: Can you post a fiddle?
It looks promising, but I thought this only works if (in this case) showinfo is actually a parent of infobox.

Comment: Here's something that looks a lot like your suggested solution, but takes into account a parent controller (as Karolis suggested). http://jsfiddle.net/8M6m7/3/

Comment: Solved it, updated my question with the final solution. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8M6m7/4/).

Comment: @Plantface great! nice solution, also I wouldn't pass all the scope, and would rather have a getter/setter a matter of taste I think

Answer (score 2):

Write a third directive, which would act either as a marker for the scope which needs to know about the variables, or as an alternative to scope. Either way, you need the third directive to be above the `{{info}}` and `infobox`, and you need to the two bottom directives to require it as a parent.

Comment: Exactly... like a $rootScope (or pseudo version). Actually, enforcing the 'require' sounds like a nice solution. Brb with a fiddle.

Comment: Well it seems to work perfectly in jsfiddle, in my own code however, the value of infomanager.info remains empty.

Comment: Solved it, updated my question with the final solution. [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/8M6m7/4/).