# Why is my directive messing up my validations?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I ripped this directive off from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16308483/968801) SO question.

```
var directive = function() {
    return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        restrict: 'A',
        link: function(scope, element, attr, ctrl) {
            function inputValue(val) {
                if (val) {
                    var digits = val.replace(/[^0-9]/g, '');

                    if (digits !== val) {
                        ctrl.$setViewValue(digits);
                        ctrl.$render();
                    }
                    return parseInt(digits, 10);
                }
                return undefined;
            }
            ctrl.$parsers.push(inputValue);
        }
    };
};

module.exports = directive;
```

I want to limit my `input` to only accept numbers, but now my other validators, like `min` and `max`, are not working.  My `input` is now always in an error state.  What part of this directive is effecting the validation lifecycle in `angular`?

Comment: did you try simply using `ng-pattern`?