# How to trigger 'change' on a hidden field bound to a scope variable with AngularJs without JQuery?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, input, dom-events

I have a complex control (button clicks, dropdowns, etc) that builds a string. So every button click/dropdown selection calls a scope function that in turn updates a scope variable that holds my result.

I bind this scope variable to a hidden field in the UI:

```
<input type="hidden" ng-model="MyComplexString" custom-validation ng-value="MyComplexString" />
```

However, when the controller function updates `MyComplexString`, `custom-validation` isn't triggered.

I tried changing the input type to text, and indeed `MyComplexString` gets updated, however, `custom-validation` still doesn't fire.

If I type in the textbox however, `custom-validation` fires as expected.

Research shows that AngularJs listens for `input` events fired on DOM elements, but the controller function doesn't fire those events on the inputs bound to scope variables after changing the scope variables. So I need to do this manually.

I hope this makes sense. Any ideas would be appreciated.

EDIT = Adding the implementation of the validation directive (implementation only checks whether something starts with a 'comma'.

```
  .directive("customValidation", function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: function(scope, ele, attrs, ctrl) {
            ctrl.$parsers.unshift(function(value) {
                var valid = false;
                if (value) {
                    // test and set the validity after update.
                    valid = value.charAt(0) == ',';
                    ctrl.$setValidity('customValFlag', valid);
                }
                return valid ? value : undefined;
            });
        }
    };
})
```

Comment: My first instinct is wondering if you could use a `$watch` and do validation there instead of binding to a hidden field? If you could provide  your `custom-validation` directive that could help

Comment: I added the directive to the main question. I wouldn't mind trying something like what you say; and I know I can drive the validation in my controller by setting a flag there, it's just feel like the wrong way about it. Plus, it's not reusable, should I ever need the same validation on a different field.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something you can do is to use a `$watch` within your directive so it is reusable. See the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16308483/2279020)

Essentially, within your link function you can `$watch` the `attrs.ngModel`, which catches any changes. Your `link` function would change to something like this:

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function (newVal) {
                //Do custom validation here
            });
        }
```

See working JSFiddle I forked [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jLz1dzty/) with two simple inputs and a hidden input using the directive that writes every change to the console

**Edit:** You might want to check for newVal and oldVal being equal to ignore the initialization call, which would look like this:

```
link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
        scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function (newVal, oldVal) {
            if(newVal !== oldVal) {
                //Do custom validation here
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! I'm still passing the control in the link function as I need to set the validity on it, but what you have here is exactly what I needed to move on.