# Angular-js: ng-repeat on a select element with a attribute directive

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a directive on a  element called on-change. The idea is when the selected value changes it gets saved in a scope variable and then another element picks it up.

My problem is if the elements of the  are static the above works fine but if I use ng-repeat, the onchange stops working.

```
<select on-change="myvar" ng-repeat="(key, value) in dataset">
   <option value="{{key}}">{{value.name}}</option>
</select>
```

here's my onchange directive:

```
.directive('onChange', function() {    
        return {
            restrict: 'A',
            scope:{'onChange':'=' },
            link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {            
                scope.$watch('onChange', function(nVal) { elm.val(nVal); });            
                elm.bind('blur', function() {
                    var currentValue = elm.val();                
                    if( scope.onChange !== currentValue ) {
                        scope.$apply(function() {
                            scope.onChange = currentValue;
                        });
                    }
                });
            }
        };        
    })
```

Any idea's on how I can overcome this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Why don't you use [ng-change](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngChange)?

Comment: Also, was your goal to make multiple dropdowns for each (key,value) pair with a single option in it? That's what this HTML would do

Comment: Is there a reason you need it set up like this? It seems like a simple `ng-model`, possibly with a `$watch` on that value, would make this much simpler

Comment: so the reason why I didn't use ng-change is because ng-change doesn't fire if you change the value programically.

Comment: I'm pretty sure your issue can be overcome if you used `ng-change` and *should* use `ng-change`. I suggest you add a fiddle of the case that's not working with the `ng-change` and we'll help you with that, right now it's just [the XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is utilize `ng-model` and `$watch` in order to catch any changes. In order to reuse it, you can actually modify your code slightly to `$watch` `ngModel`.

(I'm just guessing you meant to make a single `select` with multiple options, not multiple `select`s with a single option, so I'm changing this accordingly)

```
<select ng-model="myvar" on-change>
   <option ng-repeat="(key, value) in dataset" value="{{key}}">{{value.name}}</option>
</select>
```

New link function:

```
link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {            
    scope.$watch(attrs.ngModel, function (newVal, oldVal) {
        if(newVal !== oldVal) {
            //Change happened, react accordingly
        }
    });
}
```

See my similar answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29687201/2279020)

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you use [ngOptions](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions). In your case it should look something like:

```
<select ng-model="myVar" ng-options="key as value.name for (key, value) in dataset"></select>
```

And as some people suggested before me, use `$watch` to monitor changes in the model.

```
$scope.$watch('myVar', function(newValue, oldValue) {
   //whatever
});
```

See a simple example [here](http://jsfiddle.net/b7dnrrx4/).